# Storing pandas DF in hdf file - too many timezones error

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am reading in a large CSV file that contains data for various different countries like so:

```
def get_ods_reader():
    ods_reader = pd.read_csv("mycsv.csv", 
                             chunksize=200000, parse_dates=[6, 9, 10, 16],
                             dtype={"account_nbr": object, "REPOSSESSION_STATUS_CD": object},
                             converters={"repossession_ind": parse_int},
                             date_parser=parse_date)
    return ods_reader

with pd.HDFStore("ods_07.h5", "w") as store:
    for chunk in get_ods_reader():
        for country in countries:
            data = chunk[chunk.country_cd == country]
            data.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
            data.to_hdf(store, country, append=True, format="t", data_columns=True,
                        min_itemsize={"account_nbr": 12, "npa_stage": 8})
```

And I get the following error: `TypeError: too many timezones in this block, create separate data columns`

I specifically loop over the different countries and store them separately, in order to not get this error. Before I was trying to store everything in one file and I got the same error, which made sense to me. Why do I still get the error, although all the datetime columns should have the same timezone for each country?

**EDIT**
A possible chunk could look like this:

```
        account_nbr country_cd  date1       date2      \
4400000      111111         AT  2017-03-31  2017-07-28   
4400001      222222         CH  2017-03-31  2017-07-27   
4400002      333333         DE  2017-03-31  2017-07-29   
4400003      444444         BR  2017-03-31  2017-07-28   
4400004      555555         MX  2017-03-31  2017-07-30   

             date3        npa_stage   date4  amt1  
4400000      2017-06-27   REGULAR     NaT    10000.00   
4400001      2017-06-28   REGULAR     NaT    10000.00   
4400002      2017-06-29   REGULAR     NaT    10000.00   
4400003      2017-06-29   REGULAR     NaT    10000.00   
4400004      2017-06-28   REGULAR     NaT    10000.00
```

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:**

Demo:

```
In [355]: df = pd.DataFrame({
     ...:                  'date':pd.date_range('2018-01-01', freq='3T', periods=2,
     ...:                                       tz='Europe/Berlin')})
     ...:

In [357]: df.to_hdf('d:/temp/test.h5', 'tab', format='t', mode='a', append=True, data_columns=True)

In [358]: df1 = pd.DataFrame({
     ...:                    'date':pd.date_range('2018-01-01', freq='3T', periods=5,
     ...:                                       tz='Europe/Kiev')})
     ...:

In [359]: df1.to_hdf('d:/temp/test.h5', 'tab', format='t', mode='a', append=True, data_columns=True)
...
skipped
...
ValueError: invalid info for [date] for [tz], existing_value [Europe/Berlin] conflicts with new value [Europe/Kiev]
```

PS the error message is pretty clear and self-explanatory...

---

**Old answer:**

I'm not sure it's possible at all - if you want to store a column, which is time-zone aware, the timezone information will be saved as metadata for the **whole** column/series.

Consider the following demo:

```
In [223]: df = pd.DataFrame({
                 'date':pd.date_range('2018-01-01', freq='3T', periods=5, 
                                      tz='Europe/Berlin')})

In [224]: df
Out[224]:
                       date
0 2018-01-01 00:00:00+01:00
1 2018-01-01 00:03:00+01:00
2 2018-01-01 00:06:00+01:00
3 2018-01-01 00:09:00+01:00
4 2018-01-01 00:12:00+01:00

In [225]: df.dtypes
Out[225]:
date    datetime64[ns, Europe/Berlin]   # <----
dtype: object

In [226]: df.loc[:1, 'date'] = pd.date_range('2018-05-01', freq='30T', periods=2, 
                                             tz='Europe/Kiev')

In [227]: df.dtypes
Out[227]:
date    object   # <----
dtype: object
```

NOTE: as soon as i've added a second (different) timezone to the series - its dtype has been changed to `object`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're getting at. The DF that I want to store in the h5 file for a specific key (country) has the same timezone for the whole column. Do you mean that the error occurs because in the chunk there are dates with different timezones in the same column? Or that the timezones have to be the same for the whole h5 file not just the DF stored under a specific key?

Comment: @CrunchyCruncha, I mean that most probably the Timezone information stored once also in HDF5 file (table). Let me test it with HDF5 ...

Comment: Actually, what makes this error even stranger is that I haven't specified any timezone for the dates. The date parser converts the dates from SAS format which they are stored as in the CSV to datetime, but doesn't specify timezone. The dtype is just `purchase_dt                     datetime64[ns]`

Comment: @CrunchyCruncha, can you provide two small sample __reproducible__ data sets?

Comment: Thanks for your help, but in your demo you're getting a ValueError, while I get a TypeError. Also you append to the same key in the HDF5 file, so of course there will be an error. I want to store each country's data under a separate key, so there should be no overlapping timezones (apart from the fact that I haven't specified timezones). **EDIT**: I'll post some data in a few minutes

Comment: @CrunchyCruncha, some countries have multiple timezones ;-)

Comment: true, I also thought about that, but as I said I didn't even provide any tz, that's why I was surprised by this error. Is this data helpful? I figured it was better to show what a possible chunk would look like that then gets split into separate DFs.

Comment: @CrunchyCruncha, can add `print(chunk.dtypes)` into your loop and check whether in some chunks some columns have TZ information?

Comment: in one of the date columns, there seems to be a chunk that causes the problem. The dtype for that column (in that chunk) is `object` instead of `datetime64[ns]` as all the others. There is not a single one with TZ information though and I wonder why the field has a different format for that chunk..

Comment: @CrunchyCruncha, aha, you are getting closer... So now you can narrow down your problematic data and fix it...

Comment: thanks for your help. I think I found the issue and was able to fix it (didn't actually append to the file yet, but dtype is the same in all chunks now). The problem was the date parser which didn't return pd.NaT for some values.